# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with a Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

I'm trying to push an iOS application to iTunes Connect, but I get this error when I try to validate it in Xcode:

```
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate
```

I've seen loads of questions related to the same issue, but those didn't work for me. I follow every single step of Apple's [Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html). I check that in the build settings a distribution profile is selected for release (have tried with the wildcard and a custom one for the app) and the schema is the correct one. To ensure the app was signed with that profile, I use the `codesign -d -vvvv MyApp.app` command, and get something like:

```
Executable=/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-09-17/myapp 17-09-12 09.27.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier=com.example.MyApp
...
Authority=iPhone Distribution: My Company
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
...
```

I check the entitlements, which I haven't modified, with `security cms -D -i MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision`, getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
        <string>PR3F1X</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2012-09-17T07:20:35Z</date>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>
                ...
        </data>
    </array>
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>PR3F1X.com.example.MyApp</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>PR3F1X.*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2013-09-16T07:20:35Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>PROFILE NAME</string>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>PR3F1X</string>
    </array>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>364</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>...</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The bundle id of this app looks like com.example.MyApp, and I thought the upper cases could be the problem, but changed them and it didn't do. After that, I revoked my certificates, got fresh mobileprovision profiles and went through the whole process again, with no success.

The software I'm using is Xcode 4.3.2 with Mac OS X 10.7.4

I can't see where the problem is, I'm missing something.

EDIT 1:
Does modifying the bundle ID requires I change some other setting manually?

EDIT 2:
I just made a sample app from scratch, signed it with the same certificates and everything goes smooth, so it seems that the problem is in the configuration. I'm trying to see the differences between those two project's settings, but the only remarkable ones would be that the first one is iPad only and it uses a couple of PhoneGap plugins.

Comment: If you change your bundle ID, you need to generate a new Distribution certificate for the new ID.

Comment: @Abizern thanks!! I mean that I changed the bundle ID time ago, before creating the distribution profile for the app. Anyway, if I'm using the wildcard and I have the right App ID, I wouldn't need to create a new one, would I?

Comment: You can't use a wildcard if you're using APNS or iCloud.

Comment: This is not the case, I'm not using any of them. In fact, I think the certificates and provisioning profiles are ok, as I just verified another application with the same ones. So I think the problem must be somewhere else, but the error Xcode gives isn't very clear. It says: The signature was invalid (Is working with another project), contains disallowed entitlements (it has only the default ones), or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate (it is!! at least, that is what `codesign -dvvvv MyApp.app` says...). This is frustrating

Comment: I see you have the `get-task-allow` key defined. You don't need this as of Xcode4

Comment: I ended up creating a new project with the same bundle id, copying the files from the old one and setting up the plugins I had (it is a PhoneGap project) and everything went smooth. I still don't know where de problem was, as the presumably relevant settings with this issue were set identically in both projects

Comment: Usually when something like this happens to me its because the version number does not equal the version number I've entered in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
You had to check your Application's Signature, see [How do I check the entitlements on my Application's Signature](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG33%5d) with following:

`codesign -d --entitlements - /path/to/MyGreatApp.app`

It's `OK` and I don't know what the error you have, if you get something like:

```
Executable=/path/to/MyGreatApp.app/MyGreatApp
??qq?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>ABC123DE45.com.appleseedinc.mygreatapp</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>ABC123DE45.com.appleseedinc.mygreatapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

But If you get only:

`Executable=/path/to/MyGreatApp.app/MyGreatApp`

Then, it's a problem. Probably, you damaged the entitlements during the code resigning with `codesign` tool.

I've made next steps to fix it:

1. Archive any app in Xcode.
2. Choose 'Distribute ...'->'Save for Enterprise Ad-Hoc Deployment' as AppName.ipa
3. Unzip AppName.ipa
4. Create Application's Signature entitlements file:
   codesign -d --entitlements :enterprise.plist Payload/PathToApp.app/
5. Go to the folder where uploaded app located.
6. Create Provisioning profile entitlements file:

   security cms -D -i /path/to/the.app/embedded.mobileprovision > provision_entitlements.plist
7. Open provision_entitlements.plist and enterprise.plist. Modify settings of enterprise.plist , it should be equal to provision_entitlements.plist->Entitlements property. Save the changes.
8. When resign the app add argument --entitlements enterprise.plist to codesign tool.

   ```
   codesign -fs "iPhone Distribution: My Company" APP_DIRECTORY --entitlements enterprise.plist
   ```